# Query to fetch database value in a specific order using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch value from database by joining two table and that will be in a given order. I am giving my table below.

db_cat:

```
cat_id    cat_name   order

1          food        1

2          Drink       2

3          Ice         3
```

db_subcat:

```
subcat_id    subcat_name   cat_id   order

1            pizza          1         1

2            chiness        1         3

3          Stampede Party  1          2
 
4          Wine            2          1

5         HAPPY HOUR       3          1

6           BS             1          4
```

My expected output is given below:

```
pizza, Stampede Party, chiness,BS , Wine , HAPPY HOUR
```

From the above two table I need all `subcat_name` and that is only as per `db_cat` `order` column and `db_subcat` `order` column. Here the subcat_name under food should come first and that should also follow the `db_subcat` order column and so on. How can I write this query?

Comment: post your expected output as well,

Comment: ok,Please chcek now.

Comment: Please include what you have tried as well. SO isn't a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

you use `ORDER BY` to order the columns, you can use multiple columns in an `order by` [Read here for more info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html)

```
SELECT subcat_name
FROM db_subcat
JOIN db_cat ON db_cat.cat_id = db_subcat.cat_id
ORDER BY db_cat.order DESC, db_subcat.order DESC
```

This is pretty basic, you should read up more on mysql and find examples to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY` and try below query. It will first set order by with db_cat orderby field and then order by with db_subcat order by field.

`ASC` for ascending order and `DESC` for sescending order.

```
SELECT ds.subcat_name FROM `db_subcat` as ds 
JOIN db_cat as d ON d.cat_id=ds.cat_id 
ORDER BY d.orderby,ds.orderby ASC;
```

**Output**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solutions:

`SELECT * FROM db_subcat AS sc LEFT JOIN db_cat AS c ON sc.cat_id = c.cat_id ORDER BY c.order ASC, sc.order ASC`